# Add text with .prepend if statement

Tags: jquery, html

I am making a responsive nav bar with jQuery:
HTML:

```
<div class="head-wrap">
     <h1>Header Content</h1>

    <ul class="horiz-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Nav bar link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav bar link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav bar link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 90){
            var header = $(".horiz-nav");
            $(".horiz-nav").stop().css({'position' : 'fixed'}).animate({ 'top' : '0px'}, 0);
            header.prepend("<li>Header Content</li>");
        } else {
            $(".horiz-nav").stop().css('position', 'absolute').stop().animate({'top' : '38px'}, 100);
        }
    });
```

This works mostly as it should: it makes the nav bar switch position when the user scrolls. But what I want to do is make the `h1` above the nav bar become part of the nav bar when the page is scrolled. However this code makes dozens of copies of the `h1` (smaller, though) as the page is scrolled. How can I make only one appear before the other nav bar items?  [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/jco7tgrv/)

Comment: You could do `$('.head-wrap > h1').prependTo(header);` which will only happen once since the next time you don't have an element there.

Comment: True, but then how do I get it back to its previous position when the user scrolls back up the page?

Comment: So remove it in the else and check to see if it exists before adding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepend only if element does not exist

`if(!$('#element').length) {...}`

```
$(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 90){
            var header = $(".horiz-nav");
            $(".horiz-nav").stop().css({'position' : 'fixed'}).animate({ 'top' : '0px'}, 0);
            if(!$('#added').length) {
              header.prepend("<li id='added'>Header Content</li>");
            }
        } else {
            $(".horiz-nav").stop().css('position', 'absolute').stop().animate({'top' : '38px'}, 100);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, can't give you the check yet, but I will as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('.head-wrap > h1').prependTo(header);` in your `if` and `header.find('h1').prependTo('.head-wrap');` in your else. They will both only succeed once as the second time, that element won't be there anymore.

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var header = $(".horiz-nav");
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 90) {

        $(".horiz-nav").stop().css({
            'position': 'fixed'
        }).animate({
            'top': '0px'
        }, 0);
        $('.head-wrap > h1').prependTo(header);
    } else {
        $(".horiz-nav").stop().css('position', 'absolute').stop().animate({
            'top': '38px'
        }, 100);
        header.find('h1').prependTo('.head-wrap');
    }
});
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sf79wpt0/)